# проблема с "Rails bootstrap 4 gem"

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, gems

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.0.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0
```

Устанавливал bootstrap gem по [инструкции](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem).
В итоге мой "aplication.scss":

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Мой "aplication.js":

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

В логах сервера пусто.

Создал "layout":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>


  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <%= yield %>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Создал пустой контроллер и проверил - вот что в итоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузере никакого намека на подключение "bootstrap". Код ровно такой, какой я указал в "layout".
Может кто знает, в чем проблема? Не хочу в "assets" кидать файлы "bootstrap"'а ручками, "гем" же зачем-то придумали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не вижу у вас в лайауте подключения стилей:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```

Добавьте это в `head`.

---

И вместо этой секции:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Подключите ваш `application.js`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag'application' %>
```

А js-библиотеки (`jquery`, `tether`, и другие) подключайте в нем через `//= require`. `jquery` у вас уже подключена, а `tether` можно подключить, например, [через rails-assets.org](https://rails-assets.org/#/components/tether):

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rails-assets-tether', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'

# application.js
//= require tether

# application.css
*= require tether
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Думал, что рельсы сами как-то подставляют в подключаемые файлы то, что указано в application.scss/js. Аж слезы радости, что все заработало) Еще раз спасибо)